# Random Audio on Submit Button Click (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, button, html5-audio

I want to create a submit button, when every time you click it, it plays a random audio file.

Is there a fast way to do this with HTML/JS?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>PlayAudio</title>
      </head>
      <body>

        <script>
          function playAudio() {
            var audio = document.getElementById("MySound");
            audio.play();
          }
        </script>

        <input type="button" value="Play Audio" onclick="playAudio()">
        <audio id="MySound" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is just to play 1 sound right, not a random sound from a list?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a project with files like this:
[Project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Fbv.png)

Then you can do in your HTML & JS code like this to make the sound played randomly when the submit button is clicked:

```js
//Load the sound files into an array
const audioArr = [
    new Audio('audio/audio1.ogg'),
    new Audio('audio/audio2.ogg'),
    new Audio('audio/audio3.ogg'),
    new Audio('audio/audio4.ogg'),
    new Audio('audio/audio5.ogg'),
    new Audio('audio/audio6.ogg')
];


function playRandomAudio(){
    //Get a random index of the sound to be played
    const randomAudioIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (audioArr.length+1));

    //Play the selected sound
    audioArr[randomAudioIndex].play();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="playRandomAudio()">

<script src="test_sound.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks I've tested this but only seems to play the first audio file, any ideas?